# Bad Request Content length above 8192 not reaching WCF

Tags: .net, rest, iis, iis-6

We have a server(IIS 6.0) with 2 websites hosted

one is a proxy and other is a WCF RESTful API

now the problem is when proxy website hits the API with content length more than 8000 say for ex 9747 or 8398 it gives 400 Bad request in the proxy and in the API here is what it happenes.

WCF Dispatcher Before Call is not called

WCF Dispatcher BeforeSendReply is Called and content length is 0 there.

We have this configuration in the binding

```
<webHttpBinding >
<binding name="binding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="73400320"
        maxBufferPoolSize="73400320"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="73400320"
        transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="73400320" maxStringContentLength="73400320"
           maxArrayLength="73400320" maxBytesPerRead="73400320" maxNameTableCharCount="73400320" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

What could be done, I guess its the content length issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing adding binding1 to the bindingConfiguration in the endpoint

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding1"
                  contract="RESTService.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
```